# Permission denied (publickey) while download bzr branch

Tags: python, odoo, bazaar, launchpad

When I am try to downloading branch from launchpad.

I am facing below Error.

```
krishna@krishna-Studio-1435:~/Desktop$ bzr branch lp:openobject-addons
    Permission denied (publickey).
    ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
    Permission denied (publickey).
    bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenERP launchpad branches is transferred to Github so please download from there. Following are the links for that.

- [6.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/6.0)
- [7.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/7.0)
- [8.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0)

Comment: Hello,
 Thanks for providing Github branch information so that it is easy to get branch but I am looking for publickey issue with launchpad.So Can u give any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you have added publickey, if yes then, did you change your machine, if no then it could be resolved by adding another time SSH publickey in bazaar launchpad.

Comment: Now i have remove my ssh key with terminal.
ssk key look like below syntax:

Comment: Yuo have to add again ssh key in launchpad account

Comment: I have not changed my machine.
Now i remove my ssh key and generate new ssh key with terminal.
ssk-key look like below syntax:
ssh-rsa [my ssh-key] krishna@krishna-Studio-1435
p1=ssh-rsa   

p2=[my ssh-key]  

p3=krishna@krishna-Studio-1435

Can i use all 3 part to add an SSH key ?

Comment: I think you should follow steps https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair